# Is framing a basement floor with treated lumber code compliant?

Tags: concrete, framing, code-compliance, lumber, pressure-treated

Just finished framing a basement with a concrete floor. The floor plates are framed with treated lumber.

A carpenter that was quoting out other work made a comment that treated lumber indoors wouldn’t pass inspection. I asked why and he said "from the fumes that the chemicals give off".

Does this sound accurate?

We used a company that does a lot of framing in our area in NJ.

Comment: Where I live floor plates on slab foundations in new construction are treated lumber.

Comment: You could use sill foam and non-treated lumber, but it's easier to use PT in contact with concrete. I'll join the chorus of "it's standard and approved, but double check with your inspector".

Comment: Here you'll get dinged for NOT using treated lumber if it touches concrete.

Comment: Or this? [Should I use pressure treated wood in a basement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/133565/35141)

Comment: Or this? [Pressure treated for base plate framing on concrete](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/85037/35141)

Comment: Or this? [What kind of treatment should I use on bottom wall plates to prevent decay?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/216614/35141)

Comment: Or this? [How can I protect the soleplate when framing basement walls?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/41425/35141)